# How to find results in SQL based on how many times an entry shows up

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

I need to be able to find info using an SQL query but I am unsure how to do it. The goal is to get names for all pilots who have only flown 1 time and no more than once. Below is the schema data for the "pilot" and "flies" tables that I need to pull from.

pilots (PilotID: integer, FirstName: varchar(32), LastName: varchar(32), Birthdate: date, Address: varchar(128), Email: varchar(32), PhoneNumber: char(10), Gender: char(1), Salary: integer, HiredDate: date, Rating: integer)
        Primary key: PilotID

flies (PilotID: integer, TripID: integer)
    Foreign key: PilotID references pilots(PilotID)
    Foreign key: TripID references trips(TripID)
    Primary key: (PilotID, TripID)

What I have tried is:
    select p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.PhoneNumber
    from pilots p, flies f
    where count(f.PilotID) = 1 and f.PilotID = p.PilotID;

but I am not getting anything back, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing a `group by` clause, and you need a `having` clause to filter on an aggregate funtion such as `count()`:

```
select p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.PhoneNumber
from pilots p
inner join flies f on f.PilotID = p.PilotID
group by p.PilotID, p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.PhoneNumber
having count(*) = 1
```